# Strange behavior in "Programs and Features"

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

The window has been behaving weirdly.
When starting up, the columns are too wide. Whenever I try to adjust them so that they become thinner, they automatically go back to being really wide. It's been bugging me as it annoys me when I cannot see all information at once.
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First try right clicking and choosing `Size All Columns to Fit`.

[image]

Something else you could try would be right clicking and choosing `More`, and then manually editing the size of the coumns in pixels.

[image]

After you tried those, exit and re-open to see if the settings stuck.

---

If things *still* do not save, there could be corruption with your user profile.

I suggest doing a system integrity scan using an elevated command prompt.

Search for `cmd` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then run: `sfc /scannow`

Comment: It did not save. Scanning shows some data is corrupt, but not all of it are fixed. It also made the mouse small.
I then restarted my computer and it still acts like before and it fixed the mouse size.

Comment: Did you run `sfc /scannow`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Why did it say some data are corrupt?

Comment: Could you post the output of your scan? I can't know what you mean until I see it.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53198007/CBS.log
The log file is really big.

Comment: Might want to [read through this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-corrupted-user-profile#1TC=windows-7) and assume your user profile is corrupted.